# Can I get the position of a record in a SQL result table?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

If I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY mycolumn ASC;
```

I get a result table in a specific order.

Is there a way in SQL to efficiently find out, given a PK, what position in that result table would contain the record with my PK?

Answer (score 28):

You can count the number of records where the value that you are sorting on has a lower value than the record that you know the key value of:

```
select count(*)
from mytable
where mycolumn < (select mycolumn from mytable where key = 42)
```

Comment: +1 Simple and doesn't depend on ROW_NUMBER().  Though you'd need to add 1 to the result, or chance < to <=.

Comment: Yes, if you want the position to be one based instead of zero based.

Comment: One proviso: This method only works on unique keys (which a PK would be)

Comment: @JanM: Not exactly. It doesn't have to be a key, and it's only the one value that you compare to that have to only occur once.

Answer (score 27):

On databases that support it, you could use ROW_NUMBER() for this purpose:

```
SELECT RowNr
FROM (
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn) AS RowNr,
         mycolumn
    FROM mytable
) sub
WHERE sub.mycolumn = 42
```

The example assumes you're looking for primary key 42 :)

The subquery is necessary because something like:

```
SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mycolumn) AS RowNr
FROM mytable
WHERE sub.mycolumn = 42
```

Will always return 1; ROW_NUMBER() works after the WHERE, so to speak.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct and helpful for database engines supporting ROW_NUMBER (how speedy this is vs alternatives, as usual, requires specific measurement on a given DB).

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution for SQL Server.

Comment: I didn't give a downvote, but fwiw the OP didn't say he was using Microsoft SQL Server.  He might be, but he didn't say so or tag his question for it.

Comment: Before jumping on the downvote vagon cuz is 'm$ specific' take a minute and RTFM. ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK, PERCENT_RANK and CUME_DIST are the windowing functions specified in the ANSI standard SQL-2003 and all major vendors support them or plan to support them soon.

Comment: The problem with row-number is that it doesn't give you the "position in the table". It gives you the position in that specific result-set. It might be what the person asking wants, but it doesn't really answer the question as asked.

Comment: He says 'result table', I interpret that as 'result set'

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, A table is an unordered set. There is no such thing as "position in the table", only "position in the (ordered) resultset".

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't work that way.  It's set-based, which means that "position in that result table" is meaningless to the database.

You can keep track of position when you map the ResultSet into a collection of objects or when you iterate over it.

Comment: +1 excellent answer. SQL Server is *NOT* like dBase anymore - no more "record + 1" or such.

Comment: If position is meaningless, what is ORDER BY used for?  Or LIMIT, TOP, and ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: LIMIT, TOP, and ROW_NUMBER() are not part of the standard SQL language.

Comment: I think standard SQL abstracts away the "physical row number".   What the poster is asking is the position of a row in an ORDER BY sequence, which has a well-defined meaning in standard SQL.

Comment: CREATE INDEX is not part of any SQL standard, either.  Should I stop using indices because they're not ISO?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot get "the position of a row in a table".

The best you can get, using ORDER BY and a variant of the ROW_NUMBER construct (depends on the database engine in use), is the position of a row in the resultset of the query executed.

This position does not map back to any position in the table, though, unless the ORDER BY is on a set of clustered index columns, but even then that position might be invalidated the next second.

What I would like to know is what you intended to use this "position" for.

Answer (score 0):

### This answer applies to MySQL

**==> lower than 8.0**

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, 
    myColumn.first, 
    myColumn.second
FROM
    myTable
ORDER BY myColumn.first, myColumn.second
```

source: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

---

**==> greater than 8.0**

Please see [MySQL ROW_NUMBER() function manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) as I did not test. But it seems this function is prefered.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way you can tell that without selecting an entire subset of records. If your PK is of integer type, you can

```
select count(*) from mytable 
    where id <= 10 -- Record with ID 10
    order by mycolumn asc
```

Comment: That returns the position when ordered by id, the 'order by' clause has no effect.