# SQL - how to determine which position/order/count my selected record is in?

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, position

Imagine I have a table:

```
ID     field1       field2
---    -------      ------
111      1          11113
112      1          11114
113      1          44321
114      1          49339
115      2          53234
```

I'm interested in all records where `field1 = 1` - and specifically `field2 = 44321` , but I want to know what position it is in my selection of `field1=1` (in this case, it'd be 3).

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = 1 ORDER BY id
```

will get me all the records I want, but what I *want* to know is the number 3 (the position in the selection that 44321 is - it's the 3rd record in the query, I want to know that 3).

Is there any elegant query I can do to find out the position of the row I'm particularly interested in, or do I need to cursor fetch and walk through my recordset and find out with some counter++ business?

I know the field1 I want, I know the field2 I want - I just want to know what position field1+field2 is in the greater field1=1 query - that 3, the position).

Comment: There are some engine specific methods you can do.  What database are you using, mysql?

Comment: I think the question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907438/can-i-get-the-position-of-a-record-in-a-sql-result-table

Comment: I tagged it as "tsql" (it's SQL 2008).    @Sid -- you're right.  Where I failed is in my searching - I was thinking "position", "order", "count" - but not row number.   Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

POS column will give the position of the record that you are looking for

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.* 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)  POS
        FROM table a
     WHERE field1 = 1 
)
SELECT qry.pos
  FROM qry
 WHERE field2 = 44321
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1
FROM table
WHERE ID<(SELECT TOP 1 ID
          FROM table
          WHERE field1=1
          AND field2=44321)
```

Comment: This one works, with a small modification, the outside query also needs the field1=1 qualifier, otherwise it grabs every record in table.

Comment: I love your creative programmatic thinking, though - thanks much!