# Complex SQL Union

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Any SQL Guru's out there I could use some help! I am creating a stored procedure that I believe needs a `Union` so that all the results are brought back with 1 `SELECT` statement.
I have simplified my problem to the tables below:

**user**

`user_id      username         name            DOB
------------------------------------------------------`

`1           JohnSmith1      John Smith     01/01/1990`

`2           LisaGreen17     Lisa Green     03/07/1986`

`3            BarneyB       Barney Brown    09/12/1960`

**user_team**

`user_team_id      user_id         team_id       total_score
-------------------------------------------------------------`

`1                    1               1             29`

`2                    2               7             37`

`3                    3               2             15`

**private_league**

`priv_league_id      league_name         host_user     league_password
-------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`1                   Lisa's League           2           CSUASH429d9`

`2                  Barney's Bonanza         3           Jkap89f5I01`

**user_team_private_league_M2M**

`id      priv_league_id      user_team_id
----------------------------------------`

`1             1                 1`

`2             1                 2`

`3             1                 3`

`4             2                 1`

`5             2                 3`

I would like to run a stored procedure with an input of a **user_id** which will bring back **all leagues entered by the user**, **the host of each of those leagues**, **how many total players have entered in each league** and **what position the user is in for each of those leagues**(sorted by total score).

At the moment I have:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_private_leagues`(IN v_user_id INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE userteamid INT;

    # Retrieve user team from a user_id
    SELECT user_team_id INTO userteamid
    FROM user_team 
    WHERE user_id = v_user_id;

    # Retrieve private league name and host user (for a userteam)
    SELECT private_league.league_name, private_league.host_user
    FROM   user_team_private_league_M2M
    INNER JOIN privateleague
    ON user_team_private_league_M2M.priv_league_id=private_league.priv_league_id
    WHERE  user_team_id = userteamid;

END
```

This query does **not** include the **total number of players for each league** and the **current position of the user**

I have created a query to bring back the total users for each private league, with no user filter like so:

```
SELECT private_league_id, COUNT(*) AS total_users
FROM   classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague
GROUP BY private_league_id;
```

A query for the user's current position can be worked out by using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907438/can-i-get-the-position-of-a-record-in-a-sql-result-table) and using `total_score`.

I am extremely stuck with this at the moment - the perfect result from the SP will be as follows:

`CALL user_private_leagues(3);` (user id of BarneyB)

`priv_league_name     current_position     total_users     host_user
-----------------------------------------------------------------------`

`Lisa's League               3                 3           LisaGreen17`

`Barney's Bonanza            2                 2             BarneyB`

**Thanks!**

Comment: something about your data model does not make sense. How is user id 3 part of any team. in the user team table it lists team id as 7 but there is no team 7 in your example data.

Comment: Are you sure you need a stored procedure for this? Most of what you want is just straightforward SQL, or with subqueries.

Comment: Hogan I do apologise, I have made a couple of mistakes I'll edit them now

Comment: @ZevSpitz - using an SP improves security, even if it could be run as a single query.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I need a stored procedure because an application will call it and bring back the results

Answer (score 0):

Let take it step by step....

First ID, Count for pleague

```
SELECT private_league_id, COUNT(*) AS total_users
FROM   classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague
GROUP BY private_league_id;
```

Now add in Name and host user

```
SELECT PL.league_name, LC.uCNT, PL.host_user  
FROM (SELECT private_league_id AS pID, COUNT(*) AS uCNT
      FROM   classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague
      GROUP BY private_league_id ) AS LC
LEFT JOIN private_league PL ON PL.priv_league_id = LC.pID
```

Now add in host user name

```
SELECT PL.league_name, LC.uCNT as total_users, hu.name as host_user
FROM (SELECT private_league_id AS pID, COUNT(*) AS uCNT
      FROM   classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague
      GROUP BY private_league_id ) AS LC
LEFT JOIN private_league PL ON PL.priv_league_id = LC.pID
LEFT JOIN user hu ON PL.host_user = hu.user_id
```

Don't know where current position is.

---

This query will give users and position for each team, join to this and limit by user id to get one users position for each team:

```
select UT.user_id, 
       UT.team_id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY total_score DESC) AS team_position
from private_league L
join user_team_private_league_M2M LJ ON L.priv_league_id = LJ.priv_league_id 
join user_team UT ON LJ.user_team_id = UT.user_team_id
```

Comment: The current position is quite important though. Also, wouldn't this bring back 3 sets of results rather than 1?

Comment: @Matchday - Then you have to explain to me what current position means.  Yes this a general solution.  If you want to limit it to one user then add in another join and a where.

Comment: Current position is what position a user is in a league, when sorted by total_score. BarneyB's team has a total score of 15 - putting him last in both leagues

Comment: @Matchday - see the query above to get user position.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I didn't create the DB to test the SQL below. But you can start from there. No need for `UNION`. I didn't understand the business rule to compute the user's position in the league, since it may come from the team or the user.

```
select priv_league_id, league_name, host_user_name, count(*) as total_users
from (
      select A.priv_league_id, A.league_name, D.name as host_user_name, B.user_team_id, C.user_id, D.
      from private_league A
      join user_team_private_league_M2M B
      on A.priv_league_id = B. priv_league_id
      join user_team C
      on B.user_team_id = C. user_team_id
      join user D
      on A.host_user = D.user_id
) D
group by priv_league_id
```