# SQL, how to order by score and get position of ID in ordered list

Tags: sql

This is what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"
```

This will get the row in the table scores that has the `userId` of `${message.author.id}`.

I want to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY points
```

Now I don't know what to do from here. I would like to take this ordered list and get the position of the row with the `userId` of `${message.author.id}`.

So I basically want to order the table by the amount of points each user has, then I want to use a `userId` to see what position that user is in.

EXAMPLE:

```
userId   points
1         20
2         30
3         10
4         25
```

when I use this:

```
SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY points DESC
```

it should now look like:

```
userId   points
2         30
4         25
1         20
3         10
```

Then I want to get the position of the row a specific `userId` is in. So If I get the row of `userId = 1` I want to get out: 3.

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript...

Comment: I'm using JS and SQL

Comment: However the question is about SQL.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Witch DBMS brand?

Comment: Thanks gh9, I forgot about that, but how do I get the row position when I use the userId?

Comment: Dupe?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907438/can-i-get-the-position-of-a-record-in-a-sql-result-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the position of a record in a SQL result table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907438/can-i-get-the-position-of-a-record-in-a-sql-result-table)

Answer (score 1):

You need a ranking function, which can be done with a correlated subquery.

```
select userid,points,
(select count(distinct points) from scores where points >= s.points) as rnk
from scores s
```

Then query for required userId's.

```
select rnk 
from (select userid,points,
      (select count(distinct points) from scores where points >= s.points) as rnk
      from scores s 
     ) t
where userid=1 --change this as required
```

If your dbms supports window functions, use `dense_rank`.

```
select rnk
from (select userid,points,dense_rank() over(order by points desc) as rnk
      from scores s
     ) t
where userid=1
```

Comment: I can put ${row.points} and this gives me the points for the user, what do I replace points with to now get the rank with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY points) AS RowId, * 
FROM 
    scores 
ORDER BY 
    points
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI standard window functions (`row_number()` or `rank()`) for the ranking for everyone:

```
select s.*, rank() over (order by points desc) as ranking
from scores s;
```

(`rank()` allows ties; `row_number()` gives tied scores different but adjacent rankings.)

For a specific user:

```
select count(*) + 1
from scores s
where s.score > (select s2.score from scores s where s2.userId = @userId);
```

Comment: Why all people is guessing this is MS SQL Server?

Comment: @danihp . . . I am making no such assumption at all.

Comment: @danihp: Probably because a) the OP has not taken a moment to tell us and b) the formatting of the string.